# VBA ColumnWidth not working in adjacent columns

Tags: vba

I'm trying to size a series of pairs of columns with this code:

```
Columns(7 + 2 * x - 1).Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 7

Columns(7 + 2 * x).Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 14
```

Where x is a variable allowing me to move across the pairs of columns

But both columns end up with width 14.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First: No need to use `Select`, read https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/7599798`. So it is sufficient to write

```
Columns(7 + 2 * x - 1).ColumnWidth = 7
```

Second: You are referring to the `ActiveSheet` (the sheet that has the focus). Are you sure you want this ? The linked answer also explains details for this.